# Como somar um valor num array de objetos com reduce

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, iterator

Eu tenho um array de objetos que segue esse formato:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Batata',
    points: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    points: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tacos',
    points: 60,
  },
];
```

Eu quero percorrer esse array e obter a soma de todos os `points` em cada item do vetor. Como eu faço isso usando o reduce do Javascript??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a + b.points, 0)
```

Basicamente, o que acontece é que a função que você passa por parâmetro para o `reduce` (`a + b.points`) será executada para cada item do *array*.

O parâmetro `a` receberá o valor do resultado da última chamada (se for a primeira chamada ele receberá o valor do segundo parâmetro da função `reduce` - aquele 0).

O parâmetro `b` receberá cada item do *array*.

Algo assim:

```
1. Item do Array
a = 0
b = { name: 'Batata', points: 23 }
Retorno da função: 0 + 23

2. Item do array
a = 23
b = { name: 'Pizza', points: 50 }
Retorno da função: 23 + 50

3º Item do array
a = 73
b = { name: 'Tacos', points: 60 }
Retorno da função: 73 + 60
```

A função que você

Veja funcionando:

```js
var array = [
  {
    name: 'Batata',
    points: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    points: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tacos',
    points: 60,
  },
];

var soma = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b.points, 0)
console.log(soma)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dessa forma retornaria um objeto com a soma:

```js
var items = [
  {
    name: 'Batata',
    points: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    points: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tacos',
    points: 60,
  },
];
const reducer = (a, b) => {
  return a.points += b.points, a;
}
const soma = items.reduce(reducer, {points: 0});

console.log(soma);
```

---

Outra forma utilizado `map` para criar somente um `array` simples com os valores e utilizado `reduce` para somar:

```js
var items = [
  {
    name: 'Batata',
    points: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    points: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tacos',
    points: 60,
  },
];

const i = items
  .map(x => x.points)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(i);
```