# Como ler uma informação especifica de um arquivo JSON em ReactJS?

Tags: json, react

Estou com dificuldades para renderizar informações especificas no meu código, por exemplo, gostaria de renderizar apenas o `"id":1`, e as informações nele contida. Porem no código renderiza as informações dos dois (***id:1 e id:2***).

Esse é o arquivo JSON:

```
[
  {"id":1,  
   "Marketplace": "ML1",
   "Venda": "2452447411",
   "Nome": "Daniel",
   "Endereço": "Av. Paulista 1200",
   "Data da venda": "10/05/2020"
  },
  {
   "id":2,   
    "Marketplace": "ML1",
    "Venda": "2452432412",
    "Nome": "Hiago",
    "Endereço": "Av. Berrini 1300",
    "Data da venda": "02/04/2020"
   }
]
```

Esse é o arquivo onde esta lendo o código:

```
const TrelloCard = ({text, id, index, }) => {
    
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return(
        <Draggable draggableId={String(id)} index={index} >
            {provided => (
            <CardContainer
            ref={provided.innerRef} 
            {...provided.draggableProps} 
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            >
                <Card  >
                    <CardContent >
                        <Typography  gutterBottom> {text} </Typography>
                        <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)}>Informações</button>
                            <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false) }>
                                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                                <h3>{text} </h3>
                                <div>
                                    {Dados.map(post => {
                                        return(
                                            <>
                                            <h4>{post.Nome}</h4>
                                            <h5>{post.Venda}</h5>
                                            <h5>{post.Marketplace}</h5>
                                
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </div>
                                
                                <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}>Fechar</button>    
                            </Modal> 
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>               
                </CardContainer>
            )}        
        </Draggable>
    )
}


export default TrelloCard
```

Comment: a sua pergunta está muito confusa.

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem. A ideia é sempre pegar apenas o primeiro elemento, ou seria apenas pegar um elemento com um ID específico que você determinar?

Comment: Eu gostaria que renderizasse essas informaçoes do JSON apenas;

{"id":1,  
   "Marketplace": "ML1",
   "Venda": "2452447411",
   "Nome": "Daniel",
   "Endereço": "Av. Paulista 1200",
   "Data da venda": "10/05/2020"
  }

E não o proximo

Comment: Não seria apenas fazer um if para verificar se o id é == 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É utilizado no seu código um `map` que tem um `callBack` que passa por cada elemento do `array`, mas, você quer somente a posição **0** do `array` mediante o seu comentário, exemplo:

```
<>
    <h4>{Dados[0].Nome}</h4>
    <h5>{Dados[0].Venda}</h5>
    <h5>{Dados[0].Marketplace}</h5>
</>
```

isso resolve seu problema, e precisa dar uma lida em `array` em `javascript`, como por exemplo nos link do próprio site:

- [Diferença quando utilizando um objeto e um array sendo passados como o this no apply utilizando a função concat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/457270/diferen%c3%a7a-quando-utilizando-um-objeto-e-um-array-sendo-passados-como-o-this-no-a)
- [Como somar valores de uma array de objetos[JS], somente com funções e loop for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456864/como-somar-valores-de-uma-array-de-objetosjs-somente-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-e-loop-for)
- [Como somar um valor num array de objetos com reduce](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/455294/como-somar-um-valor-num-array-de-objetos-com-reduce)
- [Por que apontar para o mesmo endereço de memória muda um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454455/por-que-apontar-para-o-mesmo-endere%c3%a7o-de-mem%c3%b3ria-muda-um-objeto)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)